# How to check the last node value in the linked list?

Tags: java, data-structures

The code that I have written below does not check if the value I am looking for is there in the last node. How do I check the last node value?

```
public void search(int value)
{
    Node node = head;
    while(node.next!=null)
    {
        if(node.data == value)
        {
            System.out.println("Found");
        }
            node = node.next;
        }


}
```

Comment: Add one more check after you exit the `while` to check the last node

Comment: Please, checkmark rgettman answer as accepted if you deem he answered your question. @SaikumarAllam

Answer (score 1):

In your `while` condition, you're checking if the *next* node is null.  That means that when the current iteration is on the last node, it will not be checked.  What you need is to check if `node` itself is `null`, meaning you've run off the end of the linked list.

```
while (node != null)
```

This means that you won't stop the loop until after you've checked the last node, indicated by `node` being `null`.

Incidentally, unless the method signature is fixed by a homework assignment, you may want to have the method return a `boolean` indicating whether the value was found, instead of printing something if you found it and not printing anything if you didn't find it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: As the asker of this question, at your discretion, you may [accept exactly one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that you think answers your question the best.

Answer (score 1):

Last node is one comes before the end=null. Just follow idea (code can have a small bug)

```
public void search(int value)
{
    Node node = head;
    Node lastnode;

    while(node.next!=null)
    {
        if(node.data == value)
        {
            System.out.println("Found");
        }
            lastnode = node;
            node = node.next;
            if(node==null)
                System.out.println("Last node Found");   //lastnode.data
        }
}
```